# React useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, web-frontend

I have defined a array of arrays with useContext. But changing a value inside a component is updating value but not rerendering UI

```
export function BookmarkProvider({ children }) {
  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = useState({
    books: [],
    podcasts: [],
    collections: [],
  });

  const [booksmarksFetched, setBooksmarksFetched] = useState(false);

  const updateBookmarks = useCallback(
    (bookmark) => {
      setBookmarks(bookmark);
    },
    [bookmarks]
  );

  return (
    <BookmarkCreateContext.Provider
      value={{
        bookmarks,
        updateBookmarks,
        booksmarksFetched,
        setBooksmarksFetched,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </BookmarkCreateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function BookmarkContext() {
  return useContext(BookmarkCreateContext);
}
```

How should I use useContext to make the UI update where these arrays value is read
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of exporting a component `BookmarkContext` returning `useContext`, you should return a custom hook:

```
const useBookmarks = () => useContext(BookmarkCreateContext);
```

And then you can use it in your components:

```
const { bookmarks } = useBookmarks();
```

Comment: That didn't worked out

Comment: @Nilesh102001 Please update your question to include the code using the context.